# Windows 10 doesn't come back from sleep

Tags: windows-10, suspend

I updated my Dell XPS 15 laptop from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and all seems to work well, except that the machine will not wake up after going to sleep (suspend to RAM) and has to be forcefully powered off.

The machine dual-boots Debian and Windows if that matters. What to verify?

Comment: Same here, with Mac Mini running Bootcamp. Upgrade was from 8.1->10. This summarises my situation pretty well: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/the-system-firmware-has-changed-the-processors/6598ba86-a6f7-4531-a4af-daac036abfca?page=1&tm=1439261481083 but I only saw it when upgrading to 10.    Basically short sleep is ok, hibernate is ok, long sleep is not ok. I would really like long sleep.

Answer (score 0):

1. Microsoft MUST fix the sleep problem coordinating with Dell (especially L502X), Nividia GEForce and others.
2. In the mean time, use Hibernate instead of Sleep... Not a perfect solution, but it is better than forced shutdown.
3. To add a Hibernate option to the Power Options in the Start Menu, this link was helpful to me:
   http://winaero.com/blog/add-hibernate-to-the-start-menu-in-windows-10/

Good luck!...

Comment: Same problem with hibernate only for me.